# Make MessageBox stay on top of other windows

Tags: winapi, windows

I have a TimerProc which calls MessageBox. I want the MessageBox to stay on top of other windows. So for example, the parent window sets the timer, then I move another window on top of that. When the timer fires, I want to MessageBox to appear on top of the window that is covering the app. Is this possible, and how should I go about doing it?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think you want to make it System Modal as MB_SYSTEMMODAL as described [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms645505%28VS.85%29.aspx).

And/or make the window that is on top be the owner of the MessageBox.

Answer (score 2):

Do you need the same message box which is already open to go to the top? Or a new one to open up above the other windows?

**If you want the same MessageBox which is already open just brought to the top:**

I think you can get a `MessageBox` window handle if you use `EnumThreadWindows` but I've never tried it myself.  So if that works you could use its window handle in a call to `BringWindowToTop`.

If getting the MessageBox handle isn't working for you, you can simply create your own window which looks like a message box instead and then call `BringWindowToTop` instead.

**If you want to popup a new MessageBox on the top:**

If you want a new MessageBox each time you can use the `MB_SYSTEMMODAL` flag as described in the [MessageBox](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms645505(VS.85).aspx#6) documentation.  `MB_TOPMOST` is said to be ignored in Vista and above.